# Parse xmldocument based on permissions

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have been dealing with this xml document for a long time, and now it turns out that user should be able to see certain fields based on the permission level defined in the xml document. This is what the document looked previously:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<AccessControl>
    <Field>
      <name>First_Name</name>
      <label>First Name</label>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <name>Last_Name</name>
      <label>Last Name</label>
    </Field>
......
.....
</AccessControl>
```

This is how is parsed the document:

```
doc.Load(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ConfigFile.xml"));
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList xnList = root.SelectNodes("/AccessControl/Field");
 foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
 {
     string fieldName = xn["name"].InnerText;
     .....
     ....
}
```

Now I am adding a few permission nodes in the document, which will contain `field` nodes, similar to this:

```
<AccessControl>
  <Permission Name = "permissionXYZ" >
    <Field>
      <name>First_Name</name>
      <label>First Name</label>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <name>Last_Name</name>
      <label>Last Name</label>
    </Field>
    ....
  </Permission>
  <Permission Name = "permission123" >
    <Field>
    ...
    ...
    </Field>
  </Permission>
</AccessControl>
```

How do I get only the required fields based on the permission defined in the document??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ you could filter based on the attribute value and then select the Fields. Test.xml file in my example just holds your sample XML.

```
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load("c:\\temp\\test.xml");
    var fields = document.Descendants("Permission")
                .Where(i => i.Attribute("Name") != null && i.Attribute("Name").Value == "permissionXYZ")
                .Select(i => i.Descendants("Field"));
```